# mySQL where in clause

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do something like this with a where in clause, I am required to query the following data using where in.

```
select *
FROM instructor AS i
INNER JOIN teaches AS t ON i.id = t.ID
where course_id in ('C%'); -I want every course ID that begins with C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. *I want every course ID that begins with C*
> 2. *Is there a way to accomplish this with WHERE IN? That's what I am required to use. –  FatalProphet*

You can compare the first letter of the data with desired letter.

***Example***:

```
-- for other matchings too, input other comma separated letters
where LEFT( course_id, 1 ) in ( 'C' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `LIKE`:

```
select *
FROM instructor AS i
INNER JOIN teaches AS t ON i.id = t.ID
where course_id LIKE 'C%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE` instead of `IN` and you're done.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this with WHERE IN? That's what I am required to use.

Comment: Why? `LIKE` and `IN` perform different operations. One is the right tool for the job, and one isn't. It's like saying "I need to add two numbers together but I can't use arithmetic."

Comment: I'm not too sure, but your response makes me think that the individual calling the shots perhaps made a mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `like 'C%'`.

`select *
FROM instructor AS i
INNER JOIN teaches AS t ON i.id = t.ID
WHERE course_id LIKE 'C%';`

See http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php